# Removing spacing between input fields

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

There is some small spacing between the input fields that I have. How can I remove this? Additionaly the confirm button seems to have a different vertical position than the other elements, why is this? Screenshot below:

[image]

```css
.stockWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
    padding: 0px;
}

.stock {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 75px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.confirmBtn, .clearBtn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.clearBtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.confirmBtn {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="stockWrapper">
    <input type="button" class="clearBtn" value="X">
    <input type="number" class="stock">
    <input type="button" class="confirmBtn" value="✓">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The spacing between the inputs is because of the new lines
2. To align the buttons vertically add `line-height` to `.confirmBtn` and `.clearBtn`
3. For the tick sign use the appropriate HTML code `&#10003;`

Example:

```css
.stockWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
    padding: 0px;
}

.stock {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 75px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.confirmBtn, .clearBtn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
  line-height:48px;
}

.clearBtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.confirmBtn {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="stockWrapper">
    <input type="button" class="clearBtn" value="X"><input type="number" class="stock"><input type="button" class="confirmBtn" value="&#10004;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some non printable characters (hidden) between tags. Please use this:

```
<div class="stockWrapper"><input type="button" class="clearBtn" value="X"><input type="number" class="stock"><input type="button" class="confirmBtn" value="✓"></div>
```